# ios - integrating facebook with ios5 app

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to integrate facebook in my iOS 5 application. 
As mentioned in facebook documentation, i'm doing everything as they mentioned.
Usually when facebook is initiated to authorize, it will take the user to browser opening facebook website and asks to authenticate. but in my case, it opens browser and immediately it goes back to the app. I didn't understand what's happening. 
Here's the video of [the issue that I'm facing](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/945659/notreadyyet%20%281%29.m4v.mp4)

I noticed that if the facebook app is installed on iphone, above mentioned problem is noticed

Comment: have you ever authorized this app? you might try removing the app from your facebook and trying again...

Comment: Yes, I tried it as well. But I noticed that if the facebook app is installed on iphone, above mentioned problem is noticed

Answer (score 1):

Is your app ID on your project .plist?

Look at "Modify the app property list file" on the [Facebook iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

Comment: Yes, its there in the property list file and that's why its returning to the app. Else it wouldn't.

Comment: I noticed that if the facebook app is installed on iphone, above mentioned problem is noticed